# Integrating using substitution

Tags: integration

I have the following integral:
$$\int \frac{2x-\sin^{-1}x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}} \, dx$$

I divide it into two integrals: $\dfrac{2x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}$ and $\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{(1-x^2)^{1/2}}$, 
and eventually get a final result of $\dfrac{2}{3(\sin^{-1}x)^{3/2}}-\large2(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ . 
However, I get a different result with an [online integrator](http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%282x-%28arcsinx%29%29%2F%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29):

$$-\frac 1 2 (\sin^{-1}x)^2-2(1-x^2)^{1/2}$$

Where could I have been wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is because you haven't used latex fully in your post. See here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user159527. Now when you look at that $arcsin$ term, I see that it is multiplied with its derivative. So how about a u-sub?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int\frac{2x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int\frac{-du}{\sqrt u} = -2\sqrt u + C=\cdots\quad\text{ etc.}\ldots
$$
$$
\int \sin^{-1} x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int w \, dw = \frac{w^2}2 + C=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see in second integral , remember derivative if arcsinx and for first one you can use u substitution

Comment: No no why are yousaying that

Comment: Here n =1 for solving second integral

Comment: why is $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the same as $\arcsin(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just substitute $\arcsin(x)=\theta,~\sin\theta=x$, then

$$\int \frac{2x-\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx=\int\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{|\cos\theta|}\mathrm d\theta-\int\frac{\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\mathrm d\theta\\=\frac{\cos\theta}{|\cos\theta|}\left(-2\cos\theta-\int\theta\mathrm d\theta\right)=\operatorname{sgn}(\cos\theta)(2\cos\theta+\frac12\theta^2).$$